# Spring data repository not injecting with @Mock in test case class returns null?

Tags: java, spring, mockito, spring-data-jpa, springjunit4classrunner

Repository object not injecting in testcase class.
    Here is my below test class  code

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classesExternalProviderMain.class)
@ActiveProfiles(ApplicationConstants.DEVELOPMENT_PROFILE)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class EmployeeServiceTest {
@InjectMocks
EmployeeService employeeService; //not injected null 
@Mock
EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;//not injected null
@Test
public void testEmployee() {
    Mockito.when(employeeRepository.findByName(Stringname)).thenReturn(getEmployee());
    List<Employee> resultedTrackbles = employeeService.getEmployeeByName("mike");
}
private List<Employee> getEmployee(){
//here is the logic to return List<Employees>
}
}
```

Can you please help me how to inject my "EmployeeRepository" and Do  need to write any additional logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are running your test with `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` and not with `MockitoJUnitRunner`.

The mocks need to be initialized with [`MockitoAnnotations.initMocks`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/MockitoAnnotations.html#initMocks%28java.lang.Object%29):

```
@Before
public void init() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

Comment: One more question After invoking this method "employeeService.getEmployeeByName("mike")" in test case. It's internally calls  "employeeRepository.findByName(Stringname)" metod. It's already moked in test case but I didn't get List<Employee>; getting empty list. When I debug it returns empty list in my service So can you plese help what I did wrong

Comment: @VenkataRamaRaju You should post another question as it is not related to this one.

Comment: Sure, Thanks I will be add a new question